# How to create custom markers for QGIS?

Tags: qgis

Is it possible to define a custom marker as symbolizer for a point in QGIS?

I'm looking into using a variation on the "Vector Field Marker" with a couple of arrows pointing at dynamic angles (the angles being read as point attributes).

I imagine it's doable in C++ (within the QGIS code) but I'm looking for a scripting solution (python).

I'm adding a representation of what I'm trying to achieve - for two points A and B with attributes x,y,z.

[image: custom markers]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vector Field renderer is written in Python, so you could use it as a starting point for your own renderer.

Maybe it's not even necessary. What exactly are you trying to achieve? Rotating arrows can already be done with the default installation. Check the "advanced" - "rotation field" option.

Comment: I think you can write renders in Python.  There is one you can download from the Python repo that adds a new renderer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I've added a picture to make things more clear. I suppose I could create 3 separate layers using the rotation field stuff (one layer per arrow) but I don't think it's a good idea.

Comment: You're right @NathanW. I thought they were all written in Python. I'll update the answer

Comment: Thanks both for the input - I've found what I was looking for here: http://www.qgis.org/pyqgis-cookbook/vector.html#appearance-symbology-of-vector-layers

Comment: this would work too http://www.qgis.org/pyqgis-cookbook/vector.html#creating-custom-renderers